# Seamless authentication from an iPad to several enterprise apps - what are the options?

Tags: web-application, ios, sso

What are the options for authenticating users of corporate iPads which are MDM managed to access sensitive corporate web apps exposed over the internet?

The issue here is there are several web apps exposed and I do not want users to type in a long password each time. They will eventually all have their password as Password1 or find some other workaround.

I'm looking for the options and recognized architectural patterns for accomplishing this. Eg combinations of reverse proxies, certificates, SSO, FID?

Pretty new to this space so keen to learn and do some reading about proposed options.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

- For web apps, use [SAML SSO](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation). They will need to login to one web app, then other logins will be seamless. There's also OpenID and OAuth which do similar things.
- For mobile apps, you could have the user just login once when they install the app, and have a long-lived session token.
- You could use client certificates. A pretty decent solution, although not widely used.
- iOS has "login with Facebook" pretty well integrated with the OS. It may be possible to plugin custom authentication (or even use Facebook)

In fact [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146808/ios-8-safari-sharepoint-2013-windows-authentication-support) look good!